# Does PayPal's Subscription Button require users to create a PayPal account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing

I need to setup recurring billing for a service I provide on my site. The [subscription button](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-intro-outside) of PayPal seems like a great solution, however I don't want my users to create an unnecessary PayPal account. I want them to simply enter the minimal amount of information for the payment to occur (their credit card info).

Does PayPal provide this functionality?

ps: I don't mind that the users are redirected from my site to PayPal's site, I just want to be sure they're not overwhelmed with the obligation of creating *another* account.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Enhanced Recurring Payments for PayPal Payments Standard, buyers are not required to have a PayPal account. More details:

https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/erp_overview

See also:

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/buttons-require-a-paypal-account/td-p/71293

Comment: I can't use that as it's only available in US, Canada, UK and Australia. I live in Europe.

Comment: I see. Sorry, but I'm not sure if similar functionality is available in other countries. I'd suggest contacting PayPal directly to ask about this; they would have the best information.

Comment: But what about the Subscription Button... there's some info regarding it generating user/password. Maybe it doesn't require costumers to get a Paypal account?